# Getting rows where there are multiple of the same value

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe that looks something like this:

```
A    B          C
14   apple      45
14   bannaa     23
15   car        234
16   door       12
16   ear        325
```

As you can see, 14 and 16 are repeated. I want:

```
A    B          C
14   apple      45
14   bannaa     23
16   door       12
16   ear        325
```

So far I have `table(DF$A) > 1`, but how to/whats the easiest way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possible base R solution

```
indx <- with(df, ave(A, A, FUN = length))
df[indx > 1, ]
#    A      B   C
# 1 14  apple  45
# 2 14 bannaa  23
# 4 16   door  12
# 5 16    ear 325
```

Or using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N > 1], by = A]
#     A      B   C
# 1: 14  apple  45
# 2: 14 bannaa  23
# 3: 16   door  12
# 4: 16    ear 325
```

or

```
setDT(df)[, if(.N > 1) .SD, by = A]
```

Finally, a bonus solution using `rle`

```
## df <- df[order(df$A), ] # If the data isn't sorted by `A`, you''ll need to sort it first
indx <- rle(df$A)$lengths 
df[rep(indx > 1, indx), ]
#    A      B   C
# 1 14  apple  45
# 2 14 bannaa  23
# 4 16   door  12
# 5 16    ear 325
```

Comment: Hm, `.SD[.N > .]` seems quite common, isn't it? Time to optimise that then.

Comment: @Arun, I'm in (also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703764/find-duplicated-rows-with-original/26704121?s=1|0.0000#26704121)) send me an email with instructions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
indx <- duplicated(df[,"A"])|duplicated(df[,"A"],fromLast=TRUE)
df[indx,]
#   A      B   C
#1 14  apple  45
#2 14 bannaa  23
#4 16   door  12
#5 16    ear 325
```

Comment: what does fromLast do? Can you do it without the [,1] and just call the column names?

Comment: @SuperString `fromLast` means the duplication is considered from the reverse direction.  When you do `duplicated(df[,"A"])` only the elements that are duplicated  will be TRUE ie. it won't take the first value.  By reversing, we get both the `first` and all others.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already started with a different approach, here's how you could complete it:

```
x <- table(df$A)
df[df$A %in% names(x[x>1]),]
#   A      B   C
#1 14  apple  45
#2 14 bannaa  23
#4 16   door  12
#5 16    ear 325
```

This uses the fact that `names(x)` gives you the unique values of column `A` which you can subset to all those values which occur more than once by using `names(x[x>1])`.

And another option, in case you're already familiar with `dplyr`, would be:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(n() > 1)
```